# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in true at s jQuery/WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

I am creating a WordPress theme from scratch and getting following error and Slider created using Owl Carousel is not working. I am using built in jQuery with WordPress. If I switch the theme no console errors. As well I am not using any plugin for the moment.

Please let me know how can I solve this.

[image]

**Note** Here is the code I am using

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var timer = !1;
        _Ticker = $("#T1").newsTicker();
        _Ticker.on("mouseenter",function(){
            var __self = this;
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                __self.pauseTicker();
            },200);
        });
        _Ticker.on("mouseleave",function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            if(!timer) return !1;
            this.startTicker();
        });
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $(".go-top").addClass("show");
        } else {
            $(".go-top").removeClass("show");
        }
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

$('.owl-carousel-bottom').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    smartSpeed: 1500,
    autoplayTimeout:1500,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    //nav:true,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    smartSpeed: 1500,
    autoplayTimeout:1500,
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    responsive:true,
    items : 1,
    itemsDesktop : false,
    itemsDesktopSmall : false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile : false

});
});


function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

**JS Enqueue Script**

```
        wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'popper-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/popper.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'owl-carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'tickerNews-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.tickerNews.min.js' );
    wp_register_script( 'common-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/common.js' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tickerNews-script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'common-script' );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code which is generating the error. Just error is not enough to debug it. And please post the actual code not as an image.

Comment: Please update the question with the specific context where the error is occurring?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay; @Mamun; I have updated the JS Code I am using

Comment: `owl-demo` this dom element available in your html with id `#owl-demo`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem recently and tracked it back to the `responsive:true` argument. Once I remove that everything worked as it should.

Usually `.length` errors have something to do with looping. the `responsive` option takes an object filled with objects as a parameter, not a boolean.

For myself, this bug only occurred after updating from jQuery `1.7.1` to `1.12.4`

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

    //nav:true,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    smartSpeed: 1500,
    autoplayTimeout:1500,
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    // responsive:true, <-- there's the problem.
    items : 1,
    itemsDesktop : false,
    itemsDesktopSmall : false,
    itemsTablet: false,
    itemsMobile : false

});
```